# There doesn't exist an analytic function $f$ in neighbourhood of $0$ whose square is $z$

Tags: complex-analysis

I need to show that there doesn't exist an analytic function $f$ in a neighbourhood of $0$ whose square is $z$.

For this, I suppose that there does exist an analytic function $f$ such that $(f(z))^2$ = $z$. This implies that $f(z) = z^{1/2}$ but I don't think that is even a function if we are not considering multi-valued functions in this case. This verifies the above statement.

Is this argument correct?

Comment: No, this argument is not correct. "This implies that $f(z) = z^{1/2}$" is not a valid claim, because as you noted the right-hand side is not well-defined in a neighborhood of $0$! You need to figure out, and then explain, why exactly there cannot be a well-defined square-root function on a neighborhood of $0$.

Comment: Observe that $(f(0))^2=0$ implies that $f(0)=0$. Therefore, there must be $g$ analytic at $0$ such that $f(z)=zg(z)$. But then $z=(f(z))^2=z^2g(z)$, which implies that $g(z)=\frac{1}{z}$.

Comment: Why is $(f(z))^2$ = $z^2g(z)$

Comment: I missed a square also on the $g$.

Comment: And then $g(z) = \frac{1}{z^{1/2}}$ or not?

Comment: Yes, but one doesn't even need to compute $g$. It is enough to observe that $\lim_{z\to 0}g(z)$ wouldn't exist.

Comment: If yes, then shouldn't there haven't been any problem with my argument?

Comment: I disagree -- it is not correct to say "then $g(z) = 1/z^{1/2}$" because, again, there is a no such thing as $1/z^{1/2}$ (as a function of $z$ on a neighborhood of $0$).

Answer (score 0):

The argument is incomplete, but it's a good direction.

If there were a function $f(z)$ s.t. $f^2=z$ in a neighborhood of $0$ it would be a branch of $\sqrt z$. The main branch of $\sqrt z$ is defined as $e^{\frac{1}{2} Log(z)}$ and the other branch is $-e^{\frac{1}{2} Log(z)}$, So $f$ would coincide with one of them is a neighborhood of 0 (identity theorem). However, both are not analytic around $0$ since $Log(z)$ has a branch cut at $(-\infty,0]$

Comment: You haven't justified the conclusion "So $f$ would coincide with one of them is a neighborhood of $0$."

Comment: It follows from the identity theorem, fixed it

Comment: The identity theorem is local and applies on regular points. None of those functions are regular at $z=0$. You can argue equality on some open sets away from $z=0$. In a proof by contradiction one will be able to deduce anything you want. Therefore, I am not doubting the conclusion itself, but the quality of the derivation of that conclusion.